# 'Access violation in module 'coreide140.bpl' after Icon change - Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi

I was recently playing around with changing the logo in Delphi in Project > Options. I decided to change the logo to a random `.ico` file on my computer to test. Now whenever I try to open Project > options it shows this error:

`Access violation at address  00000000. Read of address 00000000.`

If I try to open it again after that, this error is shown

`Access violation at address 209931F1 in module 'coreide140.bpl.' Read of address 00000000.`

My program runs fine, however, when I close it, Embarcadero RAD Studio stops responding and I get the same application error as previously said.

Any way to fix this or change the logo of my application now another way?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Does it reproduce on blank project?

Comment: Go back to the previous version of your project's .res file from your revision control

Comment: How do I access revision control @DavidHeffernan?

Comment: @Dima The problem doesn't persist on a blank project

Comment: I don't know what revision control system you are using. Surely you are using revision control?

Comment: Then try to remember what components\wizards etc. you have installed in IDE last time.

Comment: Am still in high school, only started learning to code last year as part of the syllabus. That's likely the reason I don't know what revision control is...

Comment: OK, delete your project .res file, it will then be recreated when you next open and compile the project.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you, this worked. Appreciate the help guys